# Solving linear equation over a local ring

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, localization

Let $Z = \mathbb{C}[x, y]$, the polynomial ring in two variables over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathfrak{m} = (x - 1, y)$. Let $a, b \in \mathfrak{m}$. Consider the following linear equation of $u, v$ in $Z_{\mathfrak{m}}$ (the localization of $Z$ at $\mathfrak{m}$): 
$$\begin{bmatrix}   a & - bx \\-b & a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u \\v \end{bmatrix} = 0.$$
This linear system has nonzero solution in $Z_{\mathfrak{m}}$, since the determinant of its coefficient matrix is not invertible in $Z_{\mathfrak{m}}$. I wonder how to describe the solutions of this linear system? Is there a way to solve this system?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless $a^2=b^2x$ the system of equations has only the zero solution since $Z_m$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Yes, I figured out. Thanks!